# How to ignore partial file changes in version control system in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I know you can exclude tracking certain files and whole folders from the version control system in Android Studio. However, if I made multiple changes to a tracked file in one edit session (for instance fixed both a bug and some typos), but just want the final commit to keep track of the bug-fixing changes and not the typo-fixing changes, is there a way to do that?

p.s. (in case it is useful): the VCS I used is Git.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Files would not be in sync then which is the whole point of VCS why cant you just commit the change?

Comment: If it is **only** a typo fix & nothing else, then just add & commit your files but **do not push** it. This will save it locally but not upload it. **Later** when you are pushing some relevant code changes, this will also get uploaded.

Comment: @FirozMemon Thanks, I do not have a repository set up to push the changes to at the moment, and I just want to keep a file change history locally, so I was wondering is there a way to leave out all the typo fix changes, for instance, and only keep the bug fix changes in the commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it’s not possible.

For a tracked file, git will calculate the changes by comparing with the latest commit. So no matter you fixed a bug or typo-fixing, git will detect all the changes you made.

In a word, a file tracked by git will fully be detected or a ignored file will be fully ignored.

Comment: ah thanks, so I guess now I need to be more thoughtful about bundle up my changes together for each commit.